Refresh the page in Angular or manually entering the desired path, redirects to the home page
I am using Angular 11. My project was working fine and suddenly I faced an issue:
When I use routerlink to address a specific path, it redirects correctly to that path, but when I try to access this path manually (when I enter "localhost:4200/reunion"), it redirects to  "" (empty path) and then redirects to the home page. "localhost:4200/tableau_de_bord".
This is my app.routing.ts:
ValidateAccountComponent
const routes: Routes = [  
  {
    path: 'connexion',
    component: ConnexionComponent
  },
// ...
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'tableau_de_bord',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],

  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: AdminLayoutComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: './shared/admin-layout/admin-layout.module#AdminLayoutModule'
      }]
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'tableau_de_bord'
  },

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [
  ],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }


This is my admin-layout.routing.ts:
export const AdminLayoutRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: "", redirectTo: "tableau_de_bord", pathMatch: "prefix" },
  { path: "tableau_de_bord", component: DashboardComponent },
  {
    path: "reunion",
    component: ListReunionComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  },
// ...
];

This is admin-layout.module.ts:
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // ... other imports
    RouterModule.forChild(AdminLayoutRoutes),
    // ... other imports
  ],
  // ... other declarations and providers
})
export class AdminLayoutModule { }

I want to access the correct path when I refresh and reload the page.
When I enter "localhost:4200/connexion" or any other path existing in app.routing.ts, it works. but when I enter a path that exists in admin-layout.ts like "localhost:4200/reunion", it redirects to the home page "localhost:4200/tableau_de_bord".
I removed canActivate from app.routing.ts and from admin-layout.routing.ts, but still the same issue.
The project was working fine and I didn't touch the routing files.
I tried it in private navigation and it doesn't fix it.
I had <base href='/'> in my index.html.
Edited: this is AuthGuard code:
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  public url:any;
    constructor(private router: Router,private authService: AuthServiceService) {}

   canActivate( next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot)  : Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
        let url: string = state.url;
        return this.checkUserLogin(next, url);
    }
  
    checkUserLogin(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, url: any): boolean | UrlTree {
        if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
          const userRole = this.authService.getRole();
          if (route.data.role && route.data.role.indexOf(userRole) === -1) {
            this.router.navigate(['/connexion']);
            return false;
          }
          return true;
        }
        this.url = url
        this.router.navigate(['/connexion']);
        return false;
      }
}


There is a lot of redirects, we only need one to redirect to tableau_de_bord.
const routes: Routes = [  
  {
    path: 'connexion',
    component: ConnexionComponent
  },
// ...
  {
    path: '',
    component: AdminLayoutComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: './shared/admin-layout/admin-layout.module#AdminLayoutModule'
      }]
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'tableau_de_bord'
  },

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [
  ],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }

After that we reorder the redirects from the lazy loaded route, since they are already take care of by the parent.
export const AdminLayoutRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: "tableau_de_bord", component: DashboardComponent },
  {
    path: "reunion",
    component: ListReunionComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  },
  { path: "", redirectTo: "tableau_de_bord", pathMatch: "prefix" },
// ...
];


Thank you for your response, I had tried this but it doesn't fix the issue

@Mouna please share the code you have for auth guard

@Mouna The guard seems fine, try commenting the redirects one by one till you find the problem!
